# How to get the difference in a point?

Tags: java, point

So I recently was introduced to Points in my class. Right now I am trying to find the difference of X and then the difference of Y and then add them together. I am so lost and cant quite find the right answer. What are some options for this?

Just a heads up this is using the Point class.

Better put I dont understand the Point class that I was taught in my AP Computer Science class. Not that I don't understand how to subtract x2-x1. What command would I use to accomplish this because I continue to get errors when typing x2-x1.

Heres is what I am supposed to do:
 "In our case, the Manhattan distance is the sum of the absolute values of the differences in their coordinates; in other words, the difference in x plus the difference in y between the points."
Exact words from teacher.

Comment: `p1.x - p2.x`?  This assumes you don't care if the result is positive or negative

Comment: Post the point class here on stackoverflow for help on the revised portion of your question

Comment: Is this [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) or some other Point?

Comment: @user3183941 I have updated my answer to include how to find manhattan distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference of two X points? If so, you would do X1-X2...same with Y points... Y1-Y2.

To make sure the difference is positive, you can do

> Math.abs(p.X1-p.X2)

likewise...

> Math.abs(p.Y1-p.Y2)

then just add them together...

> Math.abs(p.X1-p.X2) + Math.abs(p.Y1-p.Y2)

After your clarifications...I have revised my answer

```
public int manhattanDistance(Point other){ //not sure why return an int...I think returning a double makes more sense..
    int xdist = Math.abs(this.x-other.x);
    int ydist = Math.abs(this.y-other.y);
    return (int)xdist+ydist; //cast to int because you must return int

}
```

or less code version...

```
    public int manhattanDistance(Point other){
    return (int)Math.abs(this.x-other.x) + Math.abs(this.y-other.y);     
}
```

Comment: Oh, come on Josh! :( Would it kill you to provide an answer that doesn't question/degrade the OP's level of intelligence?

Comment: Thanks I really just didn't understand what my teacher was asking for in his instructions. The part I quoted was just a segment of a giant list of things so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two points (in a straight line) can be calculated as:

```
   ___________________________
  /           2              2
 / (p2x - p1x)  + (p2y - p1y)
v
```

For example, the classic 3-4-5 triangle:

```
    4
  +---*
  |  /
3 | / 5
  |/
  *
```

The hypotenuse (5) can be calculated as the square root of `3 * 3 + 4 * 4`.

One way you would do that with two Point objects in Java would be with:

```
dist = (point2.x - point1.x) * (point2.x - point1.x)
     + (point2.y - point1.y) * (point2.y - point1.y);
```

though you could also use `Math.pow(something,2)` in place of the multiplications.

---

If on the other hand you wanted to find the *Manhattan* distance (as now seems evident by the extra information added to the question), you would use something like:

```
mdist = Math.abs (point2.x - point1.x) + Math.abs (point2.y - point1.y);
```

This works out the X difference (which may be negative) then takes the absolute value of that to force it to positive. Then it does the same with the Y difference and adds them together.

Comment: Don't forget the square root in that expression for `dist`.

Comment: Thanks, @David, it wasn't until I added in the 3-4-5 triangle I realised I'd left out that (fairly fundamental) bit of the formula :-)

Comment: See the OP's edit where they seem to be doing Manhattan distance.